# Interpolating values per group in a dataframe when predicted vector is shorter than measured

Tags: r, interpolation, dplyr

I have a data set with Absorbance measured at odd interval wavelengths and want to run a linear interpolation to obtain absorbance values at the desired wavelength. An example dataset

```
#Measured wavelengths
w_measured <- c(179.856, 180.241, 180.626, 181.011, 181.396, 181.781, 182.166, 182.551, 
                          182.936, 183.321, ...)
#Measured absorbance
a_measured <- c(0.2737, 0.6085, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1684, 0.3481, 0.0000, -0.0915, 
                  -0.1206,-0.3094, ...)
samples <- the grouping variable

#dataframe with absorbance measurements per wavelength interval for a X number of samples
a <- as.data.frame(cbind(w_measured, a_measured, samples))

# the wavelengths I want absorbance measurements at
w_new <- c(180, 181, 182, 183, ... etc)
```

I tried using approx fun per SampleID using `dplyr`

```
apply_fun <- function(w_new, w_measured, a_measured) {
  predfunc <- approxfun(w_measured,a_measured)
  predfunc(w_new)
}

test <- a %>%
  group_by(samples) %>%
  arrange(samples, w_measured) %>%
  mutate(predint = apply_fun(w_new, a$w_measured, a$a_measured))
```

But I get the error

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `predint`. i `predint = apply_fun(w_new, a$w_measured, a$a_measured)`. i `predint` must be
> size 2047 or 1, not 561. i The error occurred in group 1: SampleIDs =
> 02SS02BI_071717_1a_Absorbance_20-09-29-293.
>
> In addition: Warning message: Problem with `mutate()` column
> `predint`. i `predint = apply_fun(w_new, a$w_measured, a$a_measured)`.
> i collapsing to unique 'x' values i The warning occurred in group 1:
> SampleIDs = 02SS02BI_071717_1a_Absorbance_20-09-29-293.

I think because the length of the wavelength values for which I want to predict absorbance per sample is short than the length of the measured wavelengths. Is there a better way to code this so that the vector lengths of predicted values don't have to match the measured values?

Comment: Can't reproduce it so cannot try it first, but ... if your data has 100 rows and you are predicting 80 values, what do you think the original frame should look like? Typically a row is a collection of different properties grouped together as one observation, so adding 80 values to 100 observations is not right. Perhaps you should `summarize(w = w_new, predint = apply_fun(w_new, a$w_measured, a$a_measured)` instead?

Comment: @r2evans  This does run, but for some reason it provides the same interpolation for all the samples (identical values for all samples per wavelength)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).